# Kafka cluster not receiving messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have setup a 3 node Kafka cluster.  The `kafka-console-producer.sh` and `kafka-console-consumer.sh` work as advertised on the cluster in the localhost, but when I try to connect to the cluster from within a Java console application on another server, then it won't send messages to the topic.  I am using the sample code in the documentation and I have also tried the examples on GitHub as well.  The code seems to connect without errors or exceptions but the messages don't seem to be sending to the topic.

What should I be looking for to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer deep in the web...

I did not have my listeners setup so it was using the canonical hostname and not the ip address which is what i was connecting with, so after adding the ip address as the listener it all works.

Specifically

```
 listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ip address here>:9092
```